# SLSQP in ScipyOptimizeDriver only executes one iteration, takes a very long time, then exits

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, openmdao

I'm trying to use SLSQP to optimise the angle of attack of an aerofoil to place the stagnation point in a desired location. This is purely as a test case to check that my method for calculating the partials for the stagnation position is valid.

When run with COBYLA, the optimisation converges to the correct alpha (6.04144912) after 47 iterations. When run with SLSQP, it completes one iteration, then hangs for a *very* long time (10, 20 minutes or more, I didn't time it exactly), and exits with an incorrect value. The output is:

```
Driver debug print for iter coord: rank0:ScipyOptimize_SLSQP|0
--------------------------------------------------------------
Design Vars
{'alpha': array([0.5])}
Nonlinear constraints
None
Linear constraints
None
Objectives
{'obj_cmp.obj': array([0.00023868])}
Driver debug print for iter coord: rank0:ScipyOptimize_SLSQP|1
--------------------------------------------------------------
Design Vars
{'alpha': array([0.5])}
Nonlinear constraints
None
Linear constraints
None
Objectives
{'obj_cmp.obj': array([0.00023868])}
Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: 0.0002386835700364719
            Iterations: 1
            Function evaluations: 1
            Gradient evaluations: 1
Optimization Complete
-----------------------------------
Finished optimisation
```

Why might SLSQP be misbehaving like this? As far as I can tell, there are no incorrect analytical derivatives when I look at check_partials().

The code is quite long, so I put it on Pastebin here:

- core: https://pastebin.com/fKJpnWHp
- inviscid: https://pastebin.com/7Cmac5GF
- aerofoil coordinates (NACA64-012): https://pastebin.com/UZHXEsr6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You asked two questions whos answers ended up being unrelated to eachother:

1. Why is the model so slow when you use SLSQP, but fast when you use COBYLA
2. Why does SLSQP stop after one iteration?

**1) Why is SLSQP so slow?**
COBYLA is a gradient free method. SLSQP uses gradients. So the solid bet was that slow down happened when SLSQP asked for the derivatives (which COBYLA never did).
Thats where I went to look first. Computing derivatives happens in two steps: a) compute partials for each component and b) solve a linear system with those partials to compute totals. The slow down has to be in one of those two steps.

Since you can run `check_partials` without too much trouble, step (a) is not likely to be the culprit. So that means step (b) is probably where we need to speed things up.

I ran the summary utility  (`openmdao summary core.py`) on your model and saw this:

```
============== Problem Summary ============
Groups:               9
Components:          36
Max tree depth:       4
Design variables:            1   Total size:        1
Nonlinear Constraints:       0   Total size:        0
    equality:                0                      0
    inequality:              0                      0
Linear Constraints:          0   Total size:        0
    equality:                0                      0
    inequality:              0                      0
Objectives:                  1   Total size:        1
Input variables:            87   Total size:  1661820
Output variables:           44   Total size:  1169614
Total connections: 87   Total transfer data size: 1661820
```

Then I generated an N2 of your model and saw this:
[image]

So we have an output vector that is 1169614 elements long, which means your linear system is a matrix that is about 1e6x1e6. Thats pretty big, and you are using a DirectSolver to try and compute/store a factorization of it. Thats the source of the slow down. Using DirectSolvers is great for smaller models (rule of thumb, is that the output vector should be less than 10000 elements). For larger ones you need to be more careful and use more advanced linear solvers.

In your case we can see from the N2 that there is no coupling anywhere in your model (nothing in the lower triangle of the N2). Purely feed-forward models like this can use a much simpler and faster LinearRunOnce solver (which is the default if you don't set anything else). So I turned off all DirectSolvers in your model, and the derivatives became effectively instant. Make your N2 look like this instead:
[image]

The choice of best linear solver is extremely model dependent. One factor to consider is computational cost, another is numerical robustness. This issue is covered in some detail in [Section 5.3 of the OpenMDAO paper](http://file:///Users/jsgray/Downloads/Gray2019_Article_OpenMDAOAnOpen-sourceFramework%20(5).pdf), and I won't cover everything here. But very briefly here is a summary of the key considerations.

When just starting out with OpenMDAO, using DirectSolver is both the simplest and usually the fastest option. It is simple because it does not require consideration of your model structure, and it's fast because for small models OpenMDAO can assemble the Jacobian into a dense or sparse matrix and provide that for direct factorization. However, for larger models (or models with very large vectors of outputs), the cost of computing the factorization is prohibitively high. In this case, you need to break the solver structure down more intentionally, and use other linear solvers (sometimes in conjunction with the direct solver--- [see Section 5.3 of OpenMDAO paper](http://file:///Users/jsgray/Downloads/Gray2019_Article_OpenMDAOAnOpen-sourceFramework%20(5).pdf), and [this OpenMDAO doc](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/3.7.0/theory_manual/solver_api.html#writing-custom-solvers)).

You stated that you wanted to use the DirectSolver to take advantage of the sparse Jacobian storage. That was a good instinct, but the way OpenMDAO is structured this is not a problem either way. We are pretty far down in the weeds now, but since you asked I'll give a short summary explanation. As of OpenMDAO 3.7, only the DirectSolver requires an assembled Jacobian at all (and in fact, it is the linear solver itself that determines this for whatever system it is attached to). All other LinearSolvers work with a DictionaryJacobian (which stores each sub-jac keyed to the [of-var, wrt-var] pair). Each sub-jac can be stored as dense or sparse (depending on how you declared that particular partial derivative). The dictionary Jacobian is effectively a form of a sparse-matrix, though not a traditional one. The key takeaway here is that if you use the LinearRunOnce (or any other solver), then you are getting a memory efficient data storage regardless. It is only the DirectSolver that changes over to a more traditional assembly of an actual matrix object.

Regarding the issue of memory allocation. I borrowed this image from the openmdao docs

**2) Why does SLSQP stop after one iteration?**

Gradient based optimizations are very sensitive to scaling. I ploted your objective function inside your allowed design space and got this:
[image]
So we can see that the minimum is at about 6 degrees, but the objective values are TINY (about 1e-4).
As a general rule of thumb, getting your objective to around order of magnitude 1 is a good idea (we have a [scaling report](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/3.7.0/other/om_command.html#om-command-view-scaling-report) feature that helps with this). I added a reference that was about the order of magnitude of your objective:

```
p.model.add_objective('obj', ref=1e-4)
```

Then I got a good result:

```
Optimization terminated successfully    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: [3.02197589e-11]
            Iterations: 7
            Function evaluations: 9
            Gradient evaluations: 7
Optimization Complete
-----------------------------------
Finished optimization
alpha =  [6.04143334]
time:  2.1188600063323975 seconds
```

Unfortunately, scaling is just hard with gradient based optimization. Starting by scaling your objective/constraints to order-1 is a decent rule of thumb, but its common that you need to adjust things beyond that for more complex problems.

Comment: Justin, this is a great answer that could go in a docs page as-is for a real-world example of how to debug your optimization in OpenMDAO. That compendium might not exist yet, but this should definitely be a part of it!

Comment: Thanks John. The base code would be a bit tricky to use as is, but maybe if we just said "there is code here, don't look at it..." it would be ok.

Comment: Right, just your write-up alone is a good case study imo.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was using the DirectSolver to try and take advantage of sparse Jacobians - I couldn't set the assemble_jac option on LinearRunOnce. Is this a tradeoff then between memory usage and derivative compute speed?

Comment: I edited my answer to include a bit more detail about Linear solvers and memory allocation, but its not a strait forward trade off between memory usage and speed. In the case of your model, which declared the partials in a sparse manner, you'll get both the sparse memory savings and the computational speed by using the LinearRunOnce solver